# Fetch row with max occurrence in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like:

```
SALES

PROD_CODE   SALE_ID 
321         30
123         67
321         46
321         82
123         48
321         91
```

For the code:

```
SELECT PROD_CODE, COUNT(SALE_ID) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM SALES
GROUP BY PROD_CODE
ORDER BY COUNT(SALE_ID) DESC;
```

The output is:

```
PROD_CODE  TOTAL_SALES
321        4
123        2
```

But, when I am expecting only the prod_code with the maximum number of sales as the output,

like:

```
PROD_CODE
321
```

For the code:

```
SELECT PROD_CODE
FROM (SELECT MAX(COUNT(SALE_ID)) FROM SALES
GROUP BY SALE_ID);
```

The code isn't working!

Comment: Define "isn't working", please. Do you get an error? The wrong results? Also, please explain the logic behind what you're trying to achieve. Looks like you're trying to find the prod code with the most sales?

Comment: Also, what if you have two product codes which have each been sold three times? Which one(s) will you show? You haven't specified your requirements, or the actual problem you are having.

Comment: What does that mean though? The one with the maximum number of sales - so 321 because it has 4 - or the highest `sales_id` - also 321 because it has ID 91? It's ambiguous from your data. (I assumed the former, but Gordon seems to have assumed the latter, so it would help if you explained clearly in your question). If it the the maximum number of sales, again, what happens if two products have the *same* number of sales, e.g. you have two products where `total_sales` comes out as 4?

Comment: I can't see any "two products with same number of sales" from the table.

Comment: I am expecting only the prod_code with the maximum number of sales as the output

Comment: Hence "what if". Are you saying that can never happen with your real data? You can never have two products with the same number of sales? What I'm asking is how you would want to handle that ***if** it happened*. Show both? Show only one, picking one arbitrarily, or favouring one based on some other criteria?

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle 12c+, you can do:

```
select s.prod_code
from sales s
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, either

```
select s.*
from (select s.prod_code
      from sales s
      order by count(*) desc
     ) s
where rownum = 1;
```

Or:

```
select max(prod_code) over (dense_rank first order by cnt desc)
from (select s.prod_code, count(*) as cnt
      from sales s
      group by s.prod_code
     ) s
```

The first two versions fetch the entire row.  You can limit it to one or more columns is that is all you want.

Comment: Isn't the question asking for the product code with the highest number of sales, rather than the highest sales ID? From 'max occurrence' and the use of count? Requirement isn't exactly clear though. (Also third example should be `keep` not `over`?)

Comment: @Gordon I am expecting only the prod_code with the maximum number of sales as the output (Code name of the best selling product). The table is as it is, there is no "real life" data to be considered.

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use stats_mode function to fetch row/column with maximum occurrence.
Here is detailed doc for this function https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions188.htm#SQLRF06320